# How can one send an email to a gmail address from outside

Tags: authentication, smtp, gmail

If you use smtp.gmail.com, you have to specify your mail credentials. To send a mail to a gmail account you need that server right? How is it possible for outsiders to send a mail to a gmail address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself:
smtp.gmail.com is a relay server, relay servers only receive mail to redirect it to a so-called mx server, a mx server is a smtp server that is configured to receive mail and directly deliver it (to a user inside) the gmail mx server (they do not require authentication) is: gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
There are four alternative servers, you can prefix altx. to use one of those e.g. alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com

The mail program knows where to send the mail by an mx lookup database, so basically a list of @example.org and corresponding mx servers. See mxtoolbox.com for more info